Should a test in foundry necessarily start with "test" prefix?
I'm having this issue where if I run
forge test --match-test UpdatesToFunders

I'm getting the output saying
No tests match the provided pattern:
    match-test: `UpdatesToFunders`

Did you mean `UpdatesToFunders`?
Error: 
No tests to run

I've created a UpdatesToFunders test function in the test file.
Other than that, if I don't specify a particular test and just run
forge test

then it is running all the functions(tests) that start with the prefix "test"
Here's my Test.s.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {FundMe} from "../src/FundMe.sol";
import {DeployFundMe} from "../script/Deploy.s.sol";

contract FundMeTest is Test {
    FundMe fundMe;

    address user = makeAddr("user");
    uint256 constant startingBalance = 10 ether;
    uint256 constant amount = 0.1 ether;

    function setUp() external {
        DeployFundMe deployFundMe = new DeployFundMe();
        fundMe = deployFundMe.run();
        vm.deal(user, startingBalance);
    }

    function testMinFive() public view {
        assertEq(fundMe.getMin(), 5e18);
    }

    function testOwner() public view {
        console.log(address(this));
        assertEq(fundMe.getOwner(), msg.sender);
    }

    function testFund() public {
        fundMe.fund{value: 5e18}();
        assertEq(fundMe.getLog(address(this)), 5e18);
        // console.log(fundMe.log(address(this)));
    }

    function testReverts() public {
        vm.expectRevert();
        fundMe.fund{value: 1e15}();
    }

    function UpdatesToLog() public {
        vm.prank(user);
        fundMe.fund{value: amount}();

        uint256 amountFunded = fundMe.getLog(user);
        assertEq(amountFunded, amount);
    }

    function UpdatesToFunders() public {
        vm.prank(user);
        fundMe.fund{value: amount}();

        address funder = fundMe.getFunder(0);
        assertEq(funder, user);
    }
}


So is there anything I'm missing, maybe some nomenclature issues?
I'm still new to solidity and foundry so if anyone can help it would be great
Thanks in advance!

yes, prefix every function with a test keyword. It should work.

Yes Dharmin, every test case name needs to start with the 'test'.
Here is the documentation for your reference: https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/writing-tests
There it is mentioned that
test: Functions prefixed with test are run as a test case.
Eg.
function test_NumberIs42() public {}
Let me know if you have any questions. Feel free to mark this as the answer if you find this helpful.

Thank you so much!
